# Error while start and Stop processor using CURL

Tags: curl, apache-nifi

I am facing below issue ,while starting a processor by using below CURL command..Please help me on this issue.

ravi@ravi-ThinkCentre-M93p:/$ **curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"revision":{"version":1.1.1,"clientId":"test"},"processor":{"id":"eb8c6cc7-015a-1000-eb7c-6dd0941e121d","state":"RUNNING"}}' http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/process-groups/root/processors/f6a7a0e2-015b-1000-3ea2-fffe4c1e77a9**

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 15 May 2017 10:04:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.3.9.v20160517)

The specified resource could not be found.ravi@ravi-ThinkCentre-M93p:/$

Comment: Can you verify that your application is in fact running on port 8080? Try browsing to "http://localhost:8080/nifi" in your web browser.

Comment: I am able to access from browser.

Comment: I am using apache NIFI 1.1.1 also please provide a CURL command update a processor.